# Getting duplicate HTML content in a generated mail

Tags: email, sparkpost

I am running a process which generates mail using template and send mail using sparkpost via SMTP server.

Process sends approx 500K mails per day.

But I am getting duplicate HTML content in around 2-3 mails per month which is strange.

I have already ruled out some possibilities like

- Error in mail server
- mail sending logic via SMTP to sparkpost
- any loops
- Not reproducible in dev environment or any other env.

Need some pointers to get around this issue. I can't add code as there is too much logic behind it.

Sample error Content looks like this.

[image]

Comment: Please post some codes that prepare payload, template code if possible.

Comment: there is too much logic behind, Sorry can't do that.

Comment: Please just provide me some pointer where I can check. Code is written in Java

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicate HTML content". Is the entire body duplicated or only bits of it. Are you using templates? Does the duplicated data happen to be around where the template variables? From your description I am pretty sure this is related to how your system forms the message to be transmitted to the MTA.

Comment: While HTML body is appended in the mail like <body>body1</body> <body>body2</body> . Yes, I am using templates with versioning and rendering flow.

Comment: I'm curious how you're noticing the 2-3 mails out of ~15M per month. Are they test messages or something like that? In any case, I concur with @Yepher that this is likely to be an edge case in how your HTML is constructed based on something unique to an individual recipient. It's hard to be more conclusive without an example.

Comment: Okay, I will try to add output